# Connecting Salesforce and GSuite via Lightning Sync - file format error

Tags: lightning, google, sync

I have been following the instructions to connect up to GSuite to sync Calendars - instructions are [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_sync_admin_google_implement.htm&type=0).

Upon uploading the key file to Salesforce I get an error message (as in the following screenshot) stating the file format is incorrect.

[image: Error Message]

A version of the file is here:-
[image: key file]

Can anyone confirm if the file format is indeed correct? Or if not what the expect file format is?

Is it possible the error message is covering up a different error?

Many thanks.

R.

Answer (score 0):

From a response to a case submitted to SF; the solution is to

change the “token_uri"

From:  "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" 
To: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

So the error message is incorrect - the file format is correct, the value for the token_uri is incorrect.

Hopefully this is something that will be fixed by SF without the need for this workaround.